# MySQL query to get Average data consumption

Tags: mysql, sql, database

We need help in finding data like..
- In how many days "*size*" value of "type" abc will touch the  "*total*" figure (50 in this example).

> - Size of Type "abc" is increasing daily.
> - There could be multiple entries in single date
> - There could be multiple values in column "type"

## table consume

```
DateTime   |Type | size |total | seq_id
12-01-2016 | abc |   15 |   50 | 3
13-01-2016 | abc |   16 |   50 | 4
13-01-2016 | abc |   16 |   50 | 5
14-01-2016 | abc |   20 |   50 | 6
14-01-2016 | pqr |   10 |   50 | 7
15-01-2016 | abc |   25 |   50 | 8
```

Output: abc will touch 50 in n days based on average of daily consumption by n%.

Comment: Your table has no PRIMARY KEY. In time, this may prove problematic.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I forgot to add primary key while creating example - Now edited my question

Comment: Good. Also, it seems like poor design that 50 is stored in this table, right?

Comment: What are we supposed to do with two values on the same day? SUM or AVG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard question to solve it was a nice challenge. 
But i think i've got the answer you need.

**create table / insert data**

```
CREATE TABLE consume
    (`DateTime` VARCHAR(10), `Type` VARCHAR(3), `size` INT, `total` INT, `seq_id` INT)
;

INSERT INTO consume
    (`DateTime`, `Type`, `size`, `total`, `seq_id`)
VALUES
    ('12-01-2016', 'abc', 15, 50, 3),
    ('13-01-2016', 'abc', 16, 50, 4),
    ('13-01-2016', 'abc', 16, 50, 5),
    ('14-01-2016', 'abc', 20, 50, 6),
    ('14-01-2016', 'pqr', 10, 50, 7),
    ('15-01-2016', 'abc', 25, 50, 8)
;
```

The problem you face is to get the data you need so you can calculate the difference between to dates..
**Please note the dates needs to be in sequence for this query to work correctly. like 14-01-2016, 15-01-2016, 16-01-2016,(....)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT
         consume1.Type
       , consume1.DateTime
       , consume1.size  
       , consume2.DateTime
       , consume2.size
       , (consume2.size - consume1.size) size_diff
     FROM 
      consume consume1
     INNER JOIN 
       consume consume2
     ON 
       consume1.DateTime < consume2.DateTime
     WHERE
        consume1.type = 'abc'
      AND
        consume2.type = 'abc'
      AND
       ((consume2.DateTime - consume1.DateTime) = 1) 
     ORDER BY 
      consume1.seq_id ASC
```

**Result**

```
Type    DateTime      size  DateTime      size  size_diff  
------  ----------  ------  ----------  ------  -----------
abc     12-01-2016      15  13-01-2016      16            1
abc     13-01-2016      16  14-01-2016      20            4
abc     14-01-2016      20  15-01-2016      25            5
```

Now you have the correct data you can calculate the daily avg size growth with this query. 
It is using the above query as delivered table. but it only selects the fields you need.

```
 SELECT 
       TYPE
     , AVG(size_diff) daily_avg_growth
    FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT
          consume1.Type
       , (consume2.size - consume1.size) size_diff
     FROM 
      consume consume1
     INNER JOIN 
       consume consume2
     ON 
       consume1.DateTime < consume2.DateTime
     WHERE
        consume1.type = 'abc'
      AND
        consume2.type = 'abc'
      AND
       ((consume2.DateTime - consume1.DateTime) = 1) 
     ORDER BY 
      consume1.seq_id ASC 
    ) AS consume_per_day_filter
```

**Result**

```
Type    daily_avg_growth  
------  ------------------
abc     3.3333
```

Now you know the daily avg growth for type abc.
Now we can calculate the days needed with ((total- [max size]) / [daily avg growth] ) ((50 - 25) / 3.3333) = 7.5 days with this query. Note ive used CEIL in query so the result is 8 days
It is using the query above as a delivered table.

```
SELECT 
   consume.Type
 , CEIL((consume.total - MAX(consume.size)) / daily_avg_growth) "days_needed_to_50"
FROM 
 consume
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 
     TYPE
   , AVG(size_diff) daily_avg_growth
  FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT
      consume1.Type
    , (consume2.size - consume1.size) size_diff
   FROM 
    consume consume1
   INNER JOIN 
     consume consume2
   ON 
     consume1.DateTime < consume2.DateTime
   WHERE
     consume1.type = 'abc'
   AND
     consume2.type = 'abc'
   AND
     ((consume2.DateTime - consume1.DateTime) = 1)  
   ORDER BY 
    consume1.seq_id ASC 
  )
    AS consume_per_day_filter 
)
  AS consume_per_day_filter_sum
WHERE
 consume.type = 'abc'
```

**Result**

```
Type    days_needed_to_50  
------  -------------------
abc                       8
```

Comment: Well done for providing DDLs, but that GROUP BY clause has no business in a query like this.

Comment: @Strawberry the INNER JOIN generated duplicates and ive used GROUP BY to filter them out you are right using GROUP BY with no aggregate functions is pretty ugly and not the way to go... Ive updated the answer so it is using DISTINCT to filter out the duplicates to make the query more clear

Comment: @RaymondNijland, this is awesome. It is so explanatory and so good step by step execution. Problem with my attempt was I was  trying to do this in one go and did complete mess, but the logic you build is really good. Thanks a lot for your help :)